# How to professionally write a constraint, where some variables take certain values of index and some variables should not take some values of index

Tags: optimization, modeling, python, pyomo

I am using Pyomo's concrete model to model a MILP mathematical model, coming from multiproduct pipeline scheduling. Some of our continuous variables are:    `w[i,t], R[i,t], D[i,t]`. Fixing the indices i, t, we have the constraint

```
w[i,t] = w[i,t-1]  +  R[i,t]  -D[i,t]
```

where, in `R[i,t]`, $i$ takes its values from $ I_R \subset I$ and in D, $i$ comes from $ I_D \subset I$.

Now the problem is that how to model this constraint without **conditional statements** inside the rule of constraint. As we know, one way is the following code using conditional statement, but I do not want to use it. **Is there any other way?**

The rule for constraint:

```
def _cos(i,t):
    if i not in I_D and i not in I_R:
         return w[i,t] = w[i,t-1]
    if i not in I_D and i in I_R:
         return w[i,t] = w[i,t-1] +  R[i,t]
    if i not in I_R and i in I_D:
         return w[i,t] = w[i,t-1] -D[i,t]
    if i in I_R and i in I_D:
         return w[i,t] = w[i,t-1]  +  R[i,t]  -D[i,t]
```

Comment: I am not a Pyomo user, but what you are looking for is something like you want to use a specific index, in your case $i$, to represent the outer loop on the two different sets. If so, why not define two different sets/subsets and use two for-loop to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `w, R, D` variables are not in form of dictionaries (if they are the function below becomes much simpler).
I go with "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (EAFP) programming.

```
def _cos(i,t):
    try:
        _r = R[i,t]
    except KeyError:
        _r = 0
    try:
        _d = D[i,t]
    except KeyError:
        _d = 0
    return w[i,t] = w[i,t-1]  +  _r  - _d
```

Comment: No, they are not dictionaries.